# Why this tar.bz2 package does not install?

Tags: 10.10

This is what I've tried:

```
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install 7zip
[sudo] password for bapi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 7zip
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ cd\
> 
bapi@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libnjb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnjb
bapi@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install taglib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package taglib
bapi@ubuntu:~$ GNU
GNU: command not found
bapi@ubuntu:~$ clear

bapi@ubuntu:~$ cd Download
bash: cd: Download: No such file or directory
bapi@ubuntu:~$ cd Downloads
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ cd NetworkManager-0.9.0
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-0.9.0$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to disable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking paths.h usability... yes
checking paths.h presence... yes
checking for paths.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.40.0... 0.41.1 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.10.1
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for msgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... (cached) /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for /etc/redhat-release... no
checking for /etc/SuSE-release... no
checking for /etc/fedora-release... no
checking for /etc/gentoo-release... no
checking for /etc/debian_version... yes
checking for /etc/arch-release... no
checking for /etc/slackware-version... no
checking for /etc/frugalware-release... no
checking for /etc/mandriva-release... no
checking for /etc/pardus-release... no
checking for /etc/linexa-release... no
checking for /etc/exherbo-release... no
checking Linux Wireless Extensions >= 18... no
configure: error: wireless-tools or libiw development headers >= 28pre9 not installed or not functional
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-0.9.0$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-0.9.0$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for bapi: 
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-0.9.0$
```

How can i install it?

Answer (score 3):

The `./configure` command checks if you have everything you need in order to proceed to `make` and `sudo make install` your application. Check this answer for more information: [What does "./configure; make; make install" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173088/what-does-configure-make-make-install-do/173092#173092)

As you can see at the output of your `./configure` command, at the end, it says:

`configure: error: wireless-tools or libiw development headers >= 28pre9 not installed or not functional`

This means that you have to install the `wireless-tools` package. **Also**, try installing the `libiw-dev` package. Then, try re-configuring by `./configure`.

If the above command exits successfully, it will possibly create a file named `Makefile` under the current directory, which will be run once you run `make` etc afterwards.

Comment: bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-0.9.0$ sudo apt-get install wireless-tools
[sudo] password for bapi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
wireless-tools is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 367 not upgraded.
bapi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-0.9.0$                                                                   Now what?

Comment: please see the edited answer.

Comment: Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DBUS_CFLAGS
and DBUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Comment: Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DBUS_CFLAGS
and DBUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.                                                                            Now what i have to do?