# Lost/Deleted dpkg (package manager for Debian). How do I get it back?

Tags: installation, apt, dpkg

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Accidentally deleted `dpkg`. Now, packages can't be installed. So, needs an `dpkg` installer which installs packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the dpkg package for your release from
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/.

Extract the file.

`cd` to the root of the dpkg source directory.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You may need to download some packages if `./configure` fails

Comment: when I type "./configure" it says something and in end of them: "configure: error: no curses library found"...

Comment: This doesn't actually explain anything and it doesn't work currently. ./configure requires a bunch of things and it's unclear what exactly it wants.

Comment: @G_V If you have a new question, I's sure someone would love to provide a lengthy explanation.  Post your configure errors to your new question. It sounds like you need to install some packages to get dpkg to work.

Comment: @j0h I ended up doing a repair install of my OS partition, less hassle. I didn't really understand what ./configure was for or what make really did since I had never installed anything via make before. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173088/what-does-configure-make-make-install-do#173092) link helped to understand what was actually going on.

Answer (score 13):

Depending exactly what you removed, you *may* be able to rescue the situation by extracting the necessary parts from a manually downloaded `.deb` file. The trick, of course, is finding a way to unpack the `.deb` file without a working `dpkg` - fortunately there's a solution here

[How to extract and install .deb without the command dpkg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282226/65304)

---

First go to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dpkg) and download the appropriate `.deb` file for your OS version and architecture e.g.

```
mkdir debroot && cd debroot
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Now unpack the deb file using `ar` in place of the usual `dpkg -x`

```
ar -x dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

(replace `dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb` with name of the actual deb that you downloaded). You should now have the following contents

```
control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian-binary  dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

The package's files should be located in the `data.tar.gz` so to extract the `dpkg` binary file **locally**

```
tar xf data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
```

If that worked, you should have a file at `./usr/bin/dpkg`
which you can copy to your `/usr/bin` directory

```
sudo cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
```

[Note that you could untar the file directly relative to `/` using `sudo tar -C ...` but doing it in two steps just feels a little safer.]

---

If that works, I'd recommend re-installing the whole thing from the repository for consistency i.e.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

(on newer systems, you can replace `apt-get` by `apt`).

Comment: Thanks a lot .. You gave me breath as I am dying with frustration...