# What can I do, dpkg file has deleted?

Tags: command-line, dpkg

What can I do, dpkg file has deleted?

Output:

```
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost/Deleted dpkg (package manager for Debian). How do I get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287826/lost-deleted-dpkg-package-manager-for-debian-how-do-i-get-it-back)

Comment: What command did you run to get this error? I don't think it indicates that dpkg is missing. What happens if you just run `dpkg` alone?