# Accidentally deleted /usr/bin/dpkg

Tags: package-management, dpkg, delete

When trying to deal with an error I accidentally deleted the /usr/bin/dpkg file and now I can't install packages anymore.

I'm still pretty new to linux so I'm not sure what I'm doing. Please help.

I use 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: See here: [Lost/Deleted dpkg (package manager for Debian). How do I get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/a/845965/178692)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually download its package and get executable from it by

```
cd ~/Download
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
ar x dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
tar -xf data.tar.xz
sudo cp usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/dpkg
```

And then reinstall it for sure by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg` .

Comment: It might be worth noting that the downloaded `dpkg` version should match with your current Ubuntu release ... So probably try using `apt download dpkg` instead to automatically download the correct version given you have the correct repositories list.