# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100) dpkg error

Tags: dpkg

i am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
I had dpkg locked while trying to install new package. then i remove locked and found dpkg error called dpkg not found. i tried "sudo apt install dpkg" but says already install new dpkg.

output of `sudo apt install dpkg`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dpkg is already the newest version (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
```

after that i tried "`sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg`"
and found output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,136 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dpkg amd64 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3 [1,136 kB]
Fetched 1,136 kB in 1s (1,450 kB/s)                  
Could not exec dpkg!
/usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh: 7: /usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh: dpkg: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

so i cannot install dpkg and also cannot remove this error.

Note:`sudo apt upgrade` does not work at all.output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  distro-info python3-click python3-colorama
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils docker.io gnome-shell gnome-shell-common grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libnss-myhostname
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libseccomp2 libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-firmware python3-distupgrade sbsigntool systemd systemd-sysv
  ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk udev update-notifier
  update-notifier-common
37 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/126 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,394 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
/tmp/ubuntu-advantage-tools.config.idFIRB: 7: /tmp/ubuntu-advantage-tools.config.idFIRB: dpkg: not found
/tmp/grub-pc.config.YIkgdy: 1: /tmp/grub-pc.config.YIkgdy: dpkg: not found
Could not exec dpkg!
/usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh: 7: /usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh: dpkg: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Comment: Please share the output of `dpkg --version; which dpkg; ls -al $(which dpkg); file $(which dpkg); ldd $(which dpkg); dpkg -l dpkg; apt-cache policy dpkg` . If long - use pastebin.

Comment: If you've accidentally removed `/usr/bin/dpkg` then you can re-install it from the downloaded .deb file as discussed here: [Lost/Deleted dpkg (package manager for Debian). How do I get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/a/845965/178692)