# Where can I download dpkg .deb?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I had a problem when trying to install/uninstall stuff on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
dpkg: error: error trying to open /var/lib/dpkg/info/format: Not a directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I saw this topic:

[Lost/Deleted dpkg (package manager for Debian). How do I get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287826/lost-deleted-dpkg-package-manager-for-debian-how-do-i-get-it-back)

But the website [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dpkg) was down. Please tell me another website to download this dpkg.deb. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
Please tell me how to find the exact version to download.
Thanks for all!

[image: download dpkg package]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site is not down; that link is invalid. See the list of supported releases for https://packages.ubuntu.com/

For all other use [archive](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/)

Comment: You beat me to it. Could you edit your answer to include the direct link to the dpkg package in focal? https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/dpkg Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to download the source of a package is to use `apt` commands.

Just run the following commands to create a working directory and to download the .deb file:

```
mkdir DPKG
cd DPKG
apt download dpkg
```

---

To extract the files, run the following commands:

```
ar xvf *deb
tar xvf dat*
```

Now, to copy the files into place:

```
for i in [esuv]*; do sudo cp -R $i/* /$i/ ; done
```